# Jasmine javaScript exception

Tags: javascript, exception, testing, jasmine

I created simple test case in Jasmine for arithmetic operation in which it gives error **Expected function to throw an exception.** though i already did that.

**spec file**

```
describe("Arithmetic Operation",function(){
    it("adds 2 numbers i.e. 5,5",function(){
        expect(doAddition(5,5)).toEqual(10);
    });

    it("throws an error while adding", function () {   
        expect(function () {doAddition(1,2)}).toThrow(new Error("Not allowed."));
    });
});
```

**src file**

```
function doAddition(a,b){
  return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
}
```

It is working fine if i remove exception code. Any suggestion or idea what's wrong in this?

Comment: What version of Jasmine are you using? In more recent versions of Jasmine, `toThrow` does not take arguments. Use [`toThrowError`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers) instead.

Comment: It's jasmine-1.3.1. Other exceptions are working fine with **toThrow**.

Comment: In that case, `doAddition(1,2)` simply does not throw... Your test is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

You expect `doAddition(1,2)` to throw, it does not. Hence the test fail.

Comment: In case of **5,5** it is also throwing the same error and that is from jasmine **new jasmine.ExpectationResult**  exception, not the custom error message.

Comment: `parseInt(5) + parseInt(5)` **does not throw**. It returns `10`... Your first test validates that.